# Parsing Two different tags Xml Responce using Sax Parser

Tags: android, saxparser

I have to parse two different tags(CreatedClub & JoinedClub) responce using sax parser &        update responce into two different List view? My responce is as follows:

```
<root> 
    <CreatedClub>
        <rows>
            <Cid>3590</Cid>
            <ClubName>Rockets</ClubName>
            <ClubAddress>A-44A,Sector-16</ClubAddress>
            <ClubCity>Noida</ClubCity>
            <ClubLatitude>28.5775157</ClubLatitude>
            <ClubLongitude>77.3159296</ClubLongitude>
            <ClubCreatedDate>2013-05-16T08:30:29.21-04:00</ClubCreatedDate>
            <photoPath>0</photoPath>
        </rows>
    </CreatedClub>
    <JoinedClub>
        <rows>
            <Cid>512</Cid>
            <ClubName>Delhi Rockets</ClubName> 
            <ClubAddress>New Friends Colony</ClubAddress>
            <ClubCity>New Delhi</ClubCity>
            <ClubLatitude>28.5670488</ClubLatitude>
            <ClubLongitude>77.2735599</ClubLongitude> 
            <ClubCreatedDate>2013-01-10T16:26:39.707-05:00</ClubCreatedDate>
            <photoPath>0</photoPath>
        </rows>
    </JoinedClub>
</root>
```

Comment: Insted of editing, I am intruted to get answer of that question.@jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("CreatedClub")) {
        //add to list1
    }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("JoinedClub")) {
        //add to list2
        }

}
```